# WebRTC sequence of events

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Is it mandatory for the WebRTC sequence of events be allowed to execute in the order depicted in this diagram?

[WebRTC Flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Architecture/Connectivity)

The reason I ask is that my one on one WebRTC chat performs flawlessly, however when a third participant enters the  video conference, frequently I find one of the RTCPeerConnection shows iceConnectionState: "failed".

I do find that the remote stream is received before I process the Answer and before ICE Candicates are received.

How the following sequence be strictly enforced:

1. Send offer from caller.
2. Receive offer on callee.
3. Process offer on callee, generate answer and send to caller.
4. Receive and process offer on caller.
5. Send ICE candidates from caller to callee.
6. Process ICE candidates on callee.
7. Send ICE candidates from callee to caller.

The debug console shows that ICE candidates start getting generated as soon as the localmedia stream is added to the RTCPeerConnection. Should they be sent over immediately or wait till the sequence allows for sending?

Comment: For the third party, you are starting a completely new peerconnection correct?

Comment: Yes I start a new peerconnection per participant other than self.

Comment: Ok, a client should not start setting remote ice candidates until after the offer SDP is handled and accepted. That may be your issue.

Comment: By client, you mean the browser initiating the offer?

Comment: The Answerer should not start setting the Offerer's ice candidates(that you provide through the signalling server), until after it has set the Offerer's SDP.

Answer (score 4):

May be too late but for the records:

Yes, the RTCPeerConnection is based on sequence. You can refer [here](https://www.pkc.io/blog/untangling-the-webrtc-flow/) for good explanation. I too struggled to control the flow and errors didn't mean much.

Based on my successful research/implementation (Chrome v74), to enforce sequence do (you can also see any sample online or [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)):

1. Send CreateOffer from Caller (signalling part; custom transport to the other users); enable PeerConnection.onnegotiationneeded => CreateOffer() only for Caller
2. Callee can be ready with video/audio streams added it to RTCPeerConnection on its side, then accepts offer and sends answer to Caller (signalling part)
3. Caller gets the answer and adds the video/audio streams to RTCPeerConnection conditionally when PeerConnection.connectionState == "new", **the tricky parts**: condition connectionState == "new" ensures it does not add again as offer / answer might be exchanged many times with state being connecting etc. Another is, if you add video/audio streams before this step, it will be hard to control the ice sdp flowing and raising errors at wrong states (relates to comment from Benjamin Trent, here) (signalling part)
4. since offer, answer is exchanged, now many ice events flows are exchanged (signalling part)
5. Connection should be established (assuming STUN configured and if peer to peer not possible, TURN required)

I hope I have highlighted few points missing online when you get hands on into this.